# Позиционирование изображений за пределы страницы

Tags: css, изображения, position

Необходимо разместить пару картинок, по бокам веб страницы, но так чтобы они на половину выходили за пределы страницы, сделал при помощи абсолютного позиционирования и

```
overflow: hidden
```

но их границы (угол у блока) налазит на контент и перекрывает его так что нельзя взаимодействовать с ним.

```
z-index
```

не помогает как еще можно решить подобную проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример на [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/laqovip/edit?html,css,output)

Смысл: контенту задать `z` индекс с `position: relative`.